# Which of my LinkedIn and Facebook connections are on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Are there any automated ways to find out which of my connections on social networks or in my local address book also use Stack Overflow?

My research shows that LinkedIn has discontinued an API that might have been helped:
[LinkedIn API - get information about my ALL Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970016/linkedin-api-get-information-about-my-all-connections)

On the other side, I know that similar systems exist between other social networks. For example, LinkedIn allows automated searching of an address book to see which contacts are also on LinkedIn.

Comment: Not until MS buys FB and SO.

Comment: Sure, but LinkedIn expects all of its users to use their real names. Stack Overflow does not. It doesn't make sense to allow users to create user names and then let other people look them up by their email address. --Insert *V for Vendetta* quote about asking a masked person who they are here--

Comment: @BSMP You mean your dog doesn't have a LinkedIn profile? How does he make connections?

Comment: In meta, do negative votes mean the same thing as in SO? Can someone post a link about how to write a good meta post?

Comment: No worries. Meta downvotes don't count against your reputation. You just ran afoul of one of the few taboos around here: comparing SO to a social network :)

Comment: It wasn't my intention to try to use SO as a social network or make a comparison. I was just curious about which of my connections are active here and what kinds of questions they post to help with their daily work. And I thought it would be fun to attempt to answer some of their questions. Now I understand why this isn't a priority and even undesirable in some circumstances.

Answer (score 18):

> Are there any automated ways to find out which of my connections on social networks or in my local address book also use Stack Overflow?

No, there are none.

Stack Overflow isn't a social network, so it doesn't have social network features.